# Как правильно ввести аргументы бэш, шелл линукс скрипта?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnu

```
ls *.fastq | xargs -I  ./bbmap.sh
```

Как правильно ввести аргументы этого шелл скрипта? Там их два.

Одиночно, не пакетно оно работает ---

```
./bbmap.sh ref=ref.fa # creating index file from the input reference
./bbmap.sh in=SRR1163136.fastq out=mapped.sam # performing mapping/alignment and producing SAM output
```

Comment: а откуда берётся второй аргумент?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте  : [`getopts`](http://rtfm.co.ua/bash-funkciya-getopts-ispolzuem-opcii-v-skriptax/)

Краткий пример:

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts "abc" opt
do
 case $opt in
  a) echo "Found option $opt";;
  b) echo "Found option $opt";;
  c) echo "Found option $opt";;
 esac
done
```

Здесь используется цикл, который запускает `getopts` со списком допустимых опций - "abc". Найденные опции присваиваются переменной `$opt`, которая обрабатывается в `case`.

Answer (score 0):

Если необходимо получить несколько параметров за одну команду, можно так:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    parm=( $1 $2 $3 $4 );
    echo  "${parm[@]}"
```

переменная **parm** в данном случае массив, можете взять любой параметр переданный из строки.

Answer (score 0):

Ключ `-I` требует аргумента - последовательности символов в команде, которая будет заменена на имя файла из стандартного ввода по одному на строке либо через нулевой байт, если задан ключ `-0`. При этом скрипт будет вызван столько раз, сколько этих имён файлов будет получено.
Вся команда должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
ls *.fastq | xargs -I 'FILE' ./bbmap.sh in=FILE out=mapped.sam
```

Слово `FILE` можно использовать в аргументах скрипта несколько раз, но вместо него будет подставлено одно и то же имя файла, а не следующее.